# Could I make an API for another website and use it to access that website’s functionality/commands?

Tags: instagram-api

For example, let’s say I wanted to create my own Instagram API (I’m aware Instagram has an API but let’s imagine they didn’t and I wanted to make my own for them). Could I make one to post, like photos, DM, etc? Or does Instagram themselves need to make an API to allow me to access these functionality and commands?

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly make one but you could be in violation of the service's Terms of Service (ToS). If you violate the ToS, the service could shut down your access.

In the scenario where someone publishes an unofficial SDK, it can be taken down under DCMA. For example, such a private Instagram API was made and published on GitHub before Facebook filed a DCMA claim with GitHub to have it taken down:

Facebook DCMA Takedown Request:

https://github.com/github/dmca/blob/master/2020/01/2020-01-22-facebook.md

Discussion:

https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=22209892

Here's an excerpt from the Takedown Request:

> Instagram-API repository (and its forks) offers a tool expressly designed to circumvent the Company’s effective access controls and protection measures by avoiding, bypassing, removing, deactivating, or impairing the Company’s technological measures without the authority of the copyright owners or the Company. Mgp25’s Instagram-API is designed to emulate the official Instagram mobile app when communicating with Instagram’s servers, which allows users of mgp25’s Instagram-API to send and receive data (including receiving legitimate, copyrighted posts by Instagram’s users) through Instagram’s private API. Mgp25’s Instagram-API also permits other types of access to, and collection of, Instagram’s users’ copyrighted works in manners that exceed the scope of access and functionality that would be permitted by a user with a legitimate, authorized Instagram account.